# Can't change rxvt terminal width

Tags: cygwin, rxvt

How do you change the width of a rxvt terminal running in Cygwin?  I can change the number of lines by dragging, but can't figure out how to change the maximum width of any line.

Comment: Try the -geometry flag, see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BetterCygwinTerminal

Comment: -geometry is the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Resizing by dragging rxvt's window borders should still work though, and I've got no idea why it wouldn't. You could also try mintty, which is quite similar to rxvt but has a more Windows-native UI.